# ReactJS - Syntax error when trying to call a function within JSX

Tags: reactjs

I am wondering why I am facing a syntax error when I am trying to call a function in the parent component after calling props.function in the child component

Here is my code

```
export default function ProjectItemLinkDrawer(props) {

    const [item, setItem] = useState([]);

    const handleCreate = (new) => {
        setItem(...item, new)
    }

    return (
        <ItemCreateDrawer inlineCreate={(new) => handleCreate(new) } />
    )
}
```

There is syntax error coming from

```
 const handleCreate = (new) => {
                          ^
     setItem(...item, new)
 }
```

Thanks all, do guide me along, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `new` is a [reserved keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Keywords) and is an [operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new).

As such, you cannot use it for anything else other than what it is supposed to do.

To fix it, simply rename it to something else that is not a reserved word in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

`new` is a javascript keyword, so you should change to another word (example `newData`).